# Openshift app: "OutOfMemory: Java heap space"

Tags: linux, tomcat, openshift

I am getting the error `SEVERE: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space` for my OpenShift application. As the error suggests I need to increase the java heap space. I have tried ssh'ing into my open-shift server and executed `set JAVA_OPTS=-Xms1024M -Xmx1024M`. Although the error is still present.

I am deploying a `.war` file on a tomcat7 server.

What should I be doing instead to fix this problem?

Comment: Having only stacktrace, it is almost impossible to identify memory leaks. Although posting all the code doesn't make sense too. You can try profiling or using Java Flight Recorder to find out what's happening with your heap in order to have initial door to open.

Comment: The application when tested on localhost does not give this error with the same heap size, I was assuming I am configuring incorrectly on server side.

Comment: Yep, that happends. Than you definenetely should trying profiling/JFR as long as you have access to the environment where OOM occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What size gear are yo using? If it is the small gear on the free account you only get 512MB of memory to begin with.  If you need more memory you will need to upgrade to a larger gear, see http://www.openshift.com/pricing for how much memory the larger gear sizes have.

Comment: The solution to the problem is to use larger gears as suggested. I misinterpreted the space I had allocated (assumed 3 "gears" of 512mb, would combine to give 3x memory).

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to check the heap size of the existing java process
Second, you need to try and increase it using the JAVA_OPTS option or otherwise. After making the change, check the process to validate that it indeed increased the heap size
Finally, if bumping the heap does not help, then as suggested you will need to perform some level of profiling or use some other technique to troubleshoot.

Comment: Monitoring the tomcat JVM led to me discover at certain points an api call to a toolkit I am using loads ~512mb of memory (this spike was causing the out-of-memory issue). Thanks for the advice.